# How to apply the Layout modifier to each placeable individually in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a draggable modifier in my custom layout. The problem is that all my placeables are moving as a block, whereas I would like them to move individually. What would be the correct way of looping through them to make sure only one placeable is selected at a time? Or is there a better way of going about it? Here is my custom layout:

```
    @Composable
fun CustomLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val offsetX = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    val offsetY = remember { Animatable(0f) }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                    offsetY.value.roundToInt()
                )
            }
            .draggable(
                state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        offsetX.snapTo(offsetX.value + delta)
                    }
                },
                orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                onDragStarted = {},
                onDragStopped = {

                    coroutineScope.launch {

                        offsetX.animateTo(
                            targetValue = 0f,
                            animationSpec = tween(
                                durationMillis = 1000,
                                delayMillis = 0
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            ),
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val tileSize = constraints.maxWidth / 7
        val childConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = minOf(constraints.minWidth, tileSize),
            maxWidth = tileSize
        )
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(childConstraints)
        }

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            var yPosition = 0
            val xPosition = 0
            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                if (index <= 6) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = xPosition, y = yPosition)
                } else {
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        constraints.maxWidth - tileSize,
                        yPosition - placeable.height * 7
                    )
                }
                yPosition += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I would like to move one tile only at a time:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution doesn't work because you're applying the offset to the whole layout, but you need to apply it for a single item.

`Layout` only intended to layout items: in the `MeasureScope` we only have access to item sizes/positions, and we can't add modifiers to them, as those will modify the state and it'll lead to recursion.

My suggestion is to pass items count and an item generator to your Composable, so we can add both offset and draggable modifiers to each item:

```
@Composable
fun DraggableLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    count: Int,
    item: @Composable (Int, Modifier) -> Unit
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val offsetsX = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Animatable<Float, AnimationVector1D>>() }
    CustomLayout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = {
            for (i in 0 until count) {
                item(
                    i,
                    Modifier
                        .offset {
                            IntOffset(
                                offsetsX[i]?.value?.roundToInt() ?: 0,
                                0
                            )
                        }
                        .draggable(
                            state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    val offsetX = offsetsX[i] ?: Animatable(0f)
                                    offsetX.snapTo(offsetX.value + delta)
                                    offsetsX[i] = offsetX
                                }
                            },
                            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                            onDragStarted = {},
                            onDragStopped = {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    offsetsX[i]!!.animateTo(
                                        targetValue = 0f,
                                        animationSpec = tween(
                                            durationMillis = 1000,
                                            delayMillis = 0
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        ),
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun CustomLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val tileSize = constraints.maxWidth / 7
        val childConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = minOf(constraints.minWidth, tileSize),
            maxWidth = tileSize
        )
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(childConstraints)
        }

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            var yPosition = 0
            val xPosition = 0
            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                if (index <= 6) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = xPosition, y = yPosition)
                } else {
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        constraints.maxWidth - tileSize,
                        yPosition - placeable.height * 7
                    )
                }
                yPosition += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
CustomLayout(
    count = 10,
    item = { i, modifier ->
        Text(
            "Test $i",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .then(modifier)
        )
    }
)
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this looks like a perfect solution to my problem! Although I have now been told that the draggable and animation logic of my app need to be separate from the layout logic and that I need to follow the "one source of truth" pattern. But in any case, your suggested code will be helpful to me.